# Get only word before special char

Tags: c#, regex, string, nlp

I have the file with "chunked" sentences from medical sector.

The sentences looks like:

> " [ADVP again/RB ] [VP seen/VBN ] [NP is/VBZ ] [NP a/DT focal/JJ
>   asymmetry/NN ].
>
> " [NP diagnostic/JJ mammogram/NN ] [PP of/IN ] [NP the/DT left/JJ
>   breast/NN ].

I need the way to extract only **words** from those "chunks". The common rule for all sentences is that the words comes before '/' char.

Is there is option to combine REGEX or something else in order to get string without POS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to work:

```
var patt = @"\s(\b(.+?))/";
var matches = Regex.Matches("[ADVP again/RB ] [VP seen/VBN ] [NP is/VBZ ] [NP a/DT focal/JJ asymmetry/NN ].", patt);

var matchedValues = matches
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value);

var output = string.Join(" ", matchedValues);
```

=> "again seen is a focal asymmetry"

Answer (score 3):

Find all matches of this regex.

```
\w+(?=/)
```

I tested it at [RegexPal.com](http://regexpal.com). Worked like a charm.

The regex is very simple. It matches words (`\w+`) followed by a `/` without making the `/` part of match. This eliminates the need to deal with capturing groups and such. It does the 'followed by' match with `(?=/)`, which essentially matches a point which is followed immediately by a `/`. This is known as a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Here is some sample code:

```
string sentence = "[ADVP again/RB ] [VP seen/VBN ] [NP is/VBZ ] [NP a/DT focal/JJ asymmetry/NN ].";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\w+(?=/)");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
again
seen
is
a
focal
asymmetry
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a RegEx matching 
again, seen, is, a, symmetry
and
diagnostic, mammogramm, of, the, left, breast

Right?

Then... /\b([\w]+)// should work

Comment: Yes I search for the Regex that will convert the first sentence to simple string that contains:
again seen is a focal symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var val = "[ADVP again/RB ] [VP seen/VBN ] [NP is/VBZ ] [NP a/DT focal/JJ asymmetry/NN ]";    
var list = val.Split('/').Select(c => c.Split(' ').Last());
```